# Find "near duplicates" strings in R

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

I am using R to build a sentiment analysis tool and I am having some problems with duplicates. The main source of data is Twitter, and it looks like many are bypassing twitter own spam filter by adding some random text at the end of each tweet. For example

```
Click xxxxx to buy the amazing xxxxx for FREE ugjh
```

I get tons of those exact tweets with a different random string at the end. They are either from the same user or from different.

Is there any function like `duplicated` or `unique` which returns how close 2 strings are and if they are above a certain % dismiss them?

I know doing that will eventually delete real tweets from people saying exactly the same, like

```
I love xxxx !
```

but I will deal with that in the future.

Any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: `agrep` uses Levenshtein distance and would most likely be useful here.

Comment: http://rpubs.com/bbolker/6735 may be useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mentioned `agrep` above.  Here's an example with what you've explained.  By varying the `max.distance` we can adjust what gets kicked:

```
comp <- "Click xxxxx to buy the amazing xxxxx for FREE ugjh"
w <- "I love xxxx !"
x <- "Click xxxxx to purchase the awesome xxxxx for FREE bmf"

agrep(comp, c(x, w), max.distance =.4, value = TRUE)
agrep(comp, c(x, w), max.distance =.9, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Tyler I try with 1 ,agrep(comp, c(x, w), max.distance =1, value = TRUE) but I get nothing!Why such behavior?

Comment: See `?agrep` for details on max.distance with fractions and integers.